# Azure Redis Cache - how to correctly work against a replicated instance

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46992577/3199595) answer from an Azure Redis Cache team member, the Azure Redis Cache exposes a single endpoint. That endpoint is automatically routed to either the master or the slave node (on failover I assume). That answer also states that:

> Azure... requires checks on the client side to ensure that the node is
>   indeed Master or Slave

So clients see a single endpoint and have to sometime check which instance they're talking to - that raises some questions:

1. When should a Redis client care whether it talks to the master or the slave node? Is it only to prevent inconsistency during failover, or are there other concerns here?
2. How (and when) should a client check whether it's connected to the master or the slave instance? Is it by running `info replication`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-administration):

> When the master node is rebooted, Azure Redis Cache fails over to the replica node and promotes it to master. During this failover, there may be a short interval in which connections may fail to the cache.

My understanding is you never connect to the slave because it is never exposed to you. If the master goes out, the slave is promoted to master and that's what you reconnect to.

Comment: That means that clients have no way of knowing that they're connected to the slave instance. Plus, can't this result in consistency issues during/after a failover if the slave hasn't received the some writes before being promoted?

Comment: Again, my own interpretation but this probably all still applies - https://redis.io/topics/replication, which means that the master/slave will do its best to achieve consistency but it is not guaranteed (well, it's a cache not a database after all). If Microsoft is pulling extra rabbits from the hat to improve the dance.. only they can answer this.

Comment: Correct, connections to Azure Redis through ports 6379/6380 will always point to the master node in a non-clustered cache.  If a failover occurs, the system automatically re-routes all connections to the new master node post-failover.  Replication is asynchronous, so any writes that hadn't yet been replicated to the slave will be lost, which is standard Redis behavior and not specific to Azure Redis.  If you are a clustered cache, then things work slightly differently. Cluster configuration is downloaded through initial connection and then client will connect directly to all nodes in cluster.

Comment: And each node in the cluster is in a master/slave configuration, right?